# Laravel работа с очередями

Tags: php, laravel

Есть веб-приложение на laravel, с blade-шаблонами, LDAP-авторизацией, яваскриптами, в общем, по-взрослому. Называется РМ дежурного (дежурный следит за всяким разным оборудованием). Соответственно, каждая страница приложения - какой-то инструмент работы с упомянутым оборудованием.

Допустим, одна страница получает список девайсов, которые надо опросить. И, что немаловажно, начинает опрашивать (ajax)! Но вот незадача: если в это время попытаться рядом открыть другую страницу приложения, то она не прогрузится, пока не завершатся все ajax-запросы в предыдущей странице.

Подобное у меня было с API, писанным также с помощью laravel, там я вышел из положения запуском нескольких инстансов приложения, завернув их в haproxy. Подозреваю, что тут такое не прокатит ))))

Собственно, api-маршруты, используемые в js веб-приложения ведут на API-приложение с hapropxy.

Подскажите, люди добрые, что нужно сделать, чтобы несколько страничек одного веб-приложения могли функционировать независимо друг от друга?

Comment: Такое может быть только если вы настроили ваш веб-сервер на ограниченное количество рабочих (workers), которые обрабатывают входящие запросы.  Если вы запускаете локально через встроенный веб-сервер то тем более.

Comment: я никак не настраивал веб-сервер, просто выполнил php artisan serve

Comment: Тогда это и есть ваш ответ. Настройте ваш сервер через NGINX, Apache или другой, где можно назначить рабочие процессы.

Comment: спасибо, вроде помогло ) как ваш ответ пометить как решение?

Comment: Да ответа как такового и не было (были изыски), так что можете сами написать и пометить как правильный ответ. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, я последний на планете, кто не знал, что

```
php artisan serve
```

только для разработки и тестирования приложения, и никак не для рабочего применения, но ответ оставлю...

Да, надо настраивать веб-сервер nginx или apache! Конфиги есть в официальной доке к laravel (блииин! надо же еще все буквы в доке читать...)

Дополнительно надо еще разбираться с очередями в laravel, там тоже вроде много интересного есть на тему асинхронности задач